# How to do hedged reads with primaryPreferred read preference with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference-hedge-option/), if you use a "nearest" read preference, then hedged reads are automatically enabled.  The docs say hedged reads are also available if you use "primaryPreferred".  I can't seem to figure out how to enable hedged reads with primaryPreferred.

I'm using mongodb 6.0.4 and mongoose 6.10.0 (which uses mongodb native drive 4.14).

Here is the line of code I would like to modify:

```js
let mydoc = await MyMongooseModel.findOne({'foo':'bar'}).read('primaryPreferred').exec();
```

How can I modify this line to enable hedged reads? I looked through the NodeJS mongodb native driver docs, and couldn't find an example.

Comment: if you were using `connections string`, usually its already setup there, https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference/.

Comment: I don’t want it to be a global setting. Just specific queries that can be determined in code.

Comment: Enabling hedged reads can be done with the read preference: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.1/classes/ReadPreference.html#hedge

Comment: @Joe thanks, this is helpful! Would you be able to provide a couple lines of code sample that would match my code in the original post?  Like how would I pass those options into the findOne query with the mongoose model?

Comment: Try using [.setOptions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-setOptions) instead of `read`, setting the `readPreference` option to an object as described in the driver doc